# Values for chaotic scattering simulation do not match with the base case

Tags: c++, physics, runge-kutta

My first post on Stack Overflow, be gentle. I wrote a code to follow the position on the x,y plane of a particle of mass M on a potential V(r) described by a four-dimensional system of equations of motion

```
M(dv/dt)=-grad V(r),      dr/dt=v,
```

Which are solved by using the Runge Kutta 4th Order method, where r=(x,y) and v=(vx,vy); now the state of the particle is defined by x, y and the angle theta between the vector v and the positive x-axis where the magnitude of the velocity is given by

```
|v|=sqrt(2(E-V(r))/M)
```

where E is the energy in the plane and the potential V(r) is given by

```
V(r)=x^2y^2exp[-(x^2+y^2)],
```

now here is the code I made for the initial values

```
x(0)=3,
y(0)=0.3905,
vx(0)=0,
vy(0)=-sqrt(2*(E-V(x(0), y(0)))),
```

where E=0.260*(1/exp(2))

```
    // RK4
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <cmath> 

    // constant global variables
    const double M = 1.0;
    const double DeltaT = 1.0;

    // function declaration
    double f0(double t, double y0, double y1, double y2, double y3); // derivative of y0
    double f1(double t, double y0, double y1, double y2, double y3); // derivative of y1
    double f2(double t, double y0, double y1, double y2, double y3); // derivative of y2
    double f3(double t, double y0, double y1, double y2, double y3); // derivative of y3
    void rk4(double t, double h, double &y0, double  &y1, double &y2, double &y3); // method of runge kutta 4th order
    double f(double y0, double y1); //function to use

    int main(void) 
    {
      double y0, y1, y2, y3, time, E, Em;
      Em = (1.0/(exp(2.0)));
      E = 0.260*Em;
      y0 = 3.0; //x
      y1 = 0.3905; //y
      y2 = 0.0; //vx
      y3 = -(std::sqrt((2.0*(E-f(3.0, 0.0)))/M)); //vy
      for(time = 0.0; time <= 400.0; time += DeltaT) 
        {
          std::cout << time << "\t\t" << y0 << "\t\t" << y1 << "\t\t" << y2 << "\t\t" << y3 << std::endl;
          rk4(time, DeltaT, y0, y1, y2, y3);
        }


      return 0;
    }

    double f(double y0, double y1)
    {
      return y0*y0*y1*y1*(exp(-(y0*y0)-(y1*y1)));
    }

    double f0(double t, double y0, double y1, double y2, double y3)
    {
      return y2;
    }

    double f1(double t, double y0, double y1, double y2, double y3)
    {
      return y3;
    }


    double f2(double t, double y0, double y1, double y2, double y3)
    {
      return 2*y0*((y0*y0)-1)*(y1*y1)*(exp(-(y0*y0)-(y1*y1)))/M;
    }

    double f3(double t, double y0, double y1, double y2, double y3)
    {
      return 2*(y0*y0)*y1*((y1*y1)-1)*(exp(-(y0*y0)-(y1*y1)))/M;
    }


    void rk4(double t, double h, double &y0, double &y1, double &y2, double &y3) // method of runge kutta 4th order
    {
      double k10, k11, k12, k13, k20, k21, k22, k23, k30, k31, k32, k33, k40, k41, k42, k43;
      k10 = h*f0(t, y0, y1, y2, y3);
      k11 = h*f1(t, y0, y1, y2, y3);
      k12 = h*f2(t, y0, y1, y2, y3);
      k13 = h*f3(t, y0, y1, y2, y3);
      k20 = h*f0(t+h/2, y0 + k10/2, y1 + k11/2, y2 + k12/2, y3 + k13/2);
      k21 = h*f1(t+h/2, y0 + k10/2, y1 + k11/2, y2 + k12/2, y3 + k13/2);
      k22 = h*f2(t+h/2, y0 + k10/2, y1 + k11/2, y2 + k12/2, y3 + k13/2);
      k23 = h*f3(t+h/2, y0 + k10/2, y1 + k11/2, y2 + k12/2, y3 + k13/2);
      k30 = h*f0(t+h/2, y0 + k20/2, y1 + k21/2, y2 + k22/2, y3 + k23/2);
      k31 = h*f1(t+h/2, y0 + k20/2, y1 + k21/2, y2 + k22/2, y3 + k23/2);
      k32 = h*f2(t+h/2, y0 + k20/2, y1 + k21/2, y2 + k22/2, y3 + k23/2);
      k33 = h*f3(t+h/2, y0 + k20/2, y1 + k21/2, y2 + k22/2, y3 + k23/2);
      k40 = h*f0(t + h, y0 + k30, y1 + k31, y2 + k32, y3 + k33);
      k41 = h*f1(t + h, y0 + k30, y1 + k31, y2 + k32, y3 + k33);
      k42 = h*f2(t + h, y0 + k30, y1 + k31, y2 + k32, y3 + k33);
      k43 = h*f3(t + h, y0 + k30, y1 + k31, y2 + k32, y3 + k33);


      y0 = y0 + (1.0/6.0)*(k10 + 2*k20 + 2*k30 + k40);
      y1 = y1 + (1.0/6.0)*(k11 + 2*k21 + 2*k31 + k41);
      y2 = y2 + (1.0/6.0)*(k12 + 2*k22 + 2*k32 + k42);
      y3 = y3 + (1.0/6.0)*(k13 + 2*k23 + 2*k33 + k43);

    }
```

The problem here is that when I run the code with the initial conditions given, the values do not match with what it is supposed to according to the case given by the problem

*what the graphic should look like with the initial conditions given*
[image: what the graphic should look like with the initial conditions given]

now, I think i got right the implementation of the method but i do not know why the graphs do not match because when i run the code the particle goes away from the potential.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See also the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30582741/3088138 for solving ODE with `boost/numeric/odeint`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths look chaotic with sharp turns. This requires an adaptive step size, you will need to implement some step size control. Either by comparing each step with two steps of half the step length or by using a method with embedded methods of higher order like Fehlberg or Dormand-Price.

---

More immediate errors:

- define `Em` as `V(1,1)` to avoid unnecessary magic numbers
- your initial position is, if you read the chart right,

  ```
  y0 = 3.0;
  y1 = -0.3905+k*0.0010;
  ```

  with `k=-1,0,1`, note the minus sign.
- your initial velocity is horizontal, and the kinetic energy is computed to complement the potential energy at that position. Thus

  ```
  y2 = v0 = -(std::sqrt((2.0*(E-V(y0, y1)))/M));
  y3 = v1 = 0.0;
  ```

With these changes and an adaptive solver I get (in `python`) the plot

[image: reproduction of plot from cited article]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# capture the structure of the potential
f  = lambda     r :     r*np.exp(-r);
df = lambda     r : (1-r)*np.exp(-r);
V  = lambda y1,y2 : f(y1*y1)*f(y2*y2);

M= 1.0
Em = V(1.0,1.0);
E = 0.260*Em;

def prime(t,y):
    x1,x2,v1,v2 = y        
    dV_dx1 = 2*x1*df(x1*x1)*f(x2*x2);
    dV_dx2 = 2*x2*df(x2*x2)*f(x1*x1);
    return [ v1, v2, -dV_dx1/M, -dV_dx2/M ];

# prepare and draw the contour plot
X1,X0=np.ogrid[-4:3:100j,-4:3:100j]
plt.contour(X0.ravel(), X1.ravel(), V(X0,X1), Em*np.arange(0,1,0.1), colors='k', linewidths=0.3)
# display grid and fix the coordinate ranges
plt.grid();plt.autoscale(False)

for k in range(-1,1+1):

    x01 = 3.0; 
    x02 = b = -0.3905 + 0.0010*k; 
    v01 = -( ( E-V(x01,x02) )*2.0/M )**0.5; 
    v02 = 0.0; 
    print "initial position (%.4f, %.4f), initial velocity (%.4f, %.4f)" % ( x01, x02, v01, v02 )

    t0 = 0.0
    tf = 50.0
    tol = 1e-10
    y0 = [ x01, x02, v01, v02 ]
    t = np.linspace(t0,tf,501); y = odeint(lambda y,t: prime(t,y) , y0, t)

    plt.plot(y[:,0], y[:,1], label="b=%.4f" % b, linewidth=2)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Great, but in my code when I apply your corrections it still does not plot the correct paths, the "particle" goes to the opposite side and does not interact with the potential. I think the mistake is in the implementation of the runge kutta method but i do not know where is the mistake.

Comment: @spenam : Did you make `vy=0` and `vx` carrying the kinetic energy? From my adaptive step size for RK4 I see that at the close interaction with the potentials the step size needs to be as small as `0.02`. Your step size of `1` is too large. -- Please report your vector of initial values after everything in it is computed.

Comment: @spenam : I modified the C++ program in all these points and even with step size 1 the path is visually correct. There is no error in the RK4 code, even if it not very object oriented.

Comment: Yes, when I make vy=0 and vx carrying the kinetic energy, the particle follows the path of the example, I guess the book was wrong when they wrote the initial conditions of the graph, thanks a lot man!

Comment: Hi, can you give me the full code you made for the graph? I can't manage to get a nice graph with c++ and know nothing about python.

Comment: Done. Most of the graphics stuff is clear in hindsight, but putting it together it is good that search engines find many examples in tutorials and answered questions.